# Doesn't "\csname" need contain "\0"?

Tags: tex-core, csname, token

On page 40 of **The TeXbook**,

> Conversely, you can go from a list of character tokens to a control sequence by saying ‘\csname\endcsname’.

So `\csname TeX\endcsname` equals `\TeX`. However, `\TeX` contains four tokens, and those are `\`<sub>0</sub> `T`<sub>11</sub> `e`<sub>11</sub> `X`<sub>11</sub>. So, why doesn't `\csname` need the first token, `\`<sub>0</sub>, here?

Comment: No, after tokenization `\TeX` does not contain four tokens. It's a *single*  control sequence token.

Comment: Yes. I forgot that. @campa

Comment: The name of the cstoken is `TeX` not `\TeX`  it's just that to access such a token you need to prefix it by a character of catcode 0 (it does not have to be `\ `) after `\catcode\`Q=0`  you can use `\TeX` or `QTeX` these are both the same control sequence, as generated by `\csname TeX\endcsname`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the standard category codes, when TeX reads the four ***characters*** `\•T•e•X` (spaces are only for visually separating the characters) it sees `\` which has category code 0, so it knows it has to build a ***single*** token.

Thus it looks at the next one and finds `T`, which is assigned category code 11, so now TeX knows it has to build a *control word*, hence it reads all the following characters until finding one that's not of category code 11. At that point it forms a ***single*** token, in this case `|TeX|` (in the TeXbook you'd see a box around the control sequence name) and enters state *S* (skipping spaces). Never confuse the “reading part” with the tokens TeX forms from it.

The category code 0 character only serves to initiate the procedure to establish the control sequence *name* and it's not saved in any way.

If you say

```
\catcode`|=0 |TeX
```

you obtain exactly the same token you'd get with `\TeX`.

Similarly, `\csname TeX\endcsname` produces the same exact token.

Comment: How to understand this: **Never confuse the “reading part” with the tokens TeX forms from it.**?

Comment: @Y.zeng Read chapter 7.

Comment: I am reading it and now read page 40.

Comment: @Y.zeng Restart from page 37, then. In particular, look at the bottom of page 38, the dangerous bend after exercise 7.2.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot.